# usage of to-infinitive instead of gerund specifically after 'result in'

Tags: gerunds

The largest known dead zone occurred in the Gulf of Mexico in 2002, when runoff from the Mississippi River **resulted in** over 20,000 square kilometers of the Gulf area **to become** uninhabitable for oceanic life.

I think 'becoming' is more proper instead of 'to become'. I found the sentence above.
If the sentence above is correct, I'd like to know why 'to become' is right.
because to-infinitive is representing future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That construction is definitely defective. Gerund-participials (*becoming* in this case) occur freely as complement of a preposition (*in* in this case). *To*-infinitivals occur only under very restrictive conditions. The only prepositional expressions that take *to*-infinitivals other than interrogatives as direct complements are purposive *in order*, and *as if/though* (CaGELp1262).

Comment: You could also argue that gerund-participials are more like nouns than infinitivals are in that they can invert with the subject in interrogatives.